# Should I use Amazon VPC in Amazon EC2 when I have multiple servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, multiserver

I am planning to have a multi server architecture in amazon EC2 where the servers need to talk to each other. These servers need to be located in different amazon regions (different datacenters). Can I just use the internal network of the amazon ec2? What are the security issues? Should I mandatorily use Amazon VPC in this setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jam ,

If you are planning to create instances on different regions then go for VPC ,because VPC gives you more security .You can restrict these machines for limited external access also .
As security part , VPC is better than classic EC2 instances ,as you can even only allow VPC to VPC connections also .

Comment: Thanks. I saw that per region I can create only one vpc, how does the different vpc's talk to each other ?

Comment: jam , you can follow the link http://aws.amazon.com/articles/0639686206802544#_Toc331614404   for more ino , it solves your problem